# web.xml can't mark spring ServletDispatcher Properly

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

So I'm making simple project for testing Spring Framework by this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U7i1gRv5nZY), and encounter a problem that I can't figure out.

My project structure:

[image: Project structure]

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.itaSS.controller" />

</beans>
```

HomeController.java:

```
package com.itaSS.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String home() {
        return "/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp";
    }
}
```

So when after deploying war on tomcat and trying go for localhost:8080/home.html
I get this:

[image: Tomcat response]

I'm sure that in web.xml is some mistake or I'm missed something.
I'll be very grateful if someone helped me with this!

Comment: Change your `@RequestMapping` for `"/home.html"`.

Comment: Doesn't work, and I'm not sure that this is the problem, since in web.xml we have mapping for *.html.

Comment: Make sure you have the right artifact deployed.

Comment: localhost:8080 show me index.jsp, so the artifact is deployed.

Comment: Enable debug logging and check what is happening. I suspect that your controller is found but that your JSP isn't.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are missing below line in your dispatcher-servlet.xml file.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately no result, and in tutorial he doesn't use his tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a ViewResolver in your application context file `dispatcher-servlet.xml` like this :

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Unfortunately no result.

Comment: @Arcaniel Add your bean controller in your application context and <mvc:annotation-driven/> as RE350 suggest.

Comment: Check you url, what i gave you should work.Did you try http://localhost:8080/museum-web/home.html instead of http://localhost:8080/home.html

Comment: webapp mapping set on localhost:8080/
Just tried not working.